# What is covered in "Grunfeld Defense: Russian Variations" (1988) by Eric Schiller?

Tags: opening, books, grunfeld-defense

I'm interested in the Russian system of the [grunfeld-defense](/questions/tagged/grunfeld-defense):

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "10"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 d54. Nf3 Bg7 5. Qb3
```

I'd like to buy a book on this line alone (I'm not interested in books offering other mainlines, as I much prefer the Russian).

That's when I came across *Grunfeld Defense: Russian Variations* (1988) by Eric Schiller for sale on Amazon.

My problem is that I don't know what I'm buying, as there are no reviews, previews, blurb, contents or even number of pages for me to weigh up the benefits of purchasing.

So, my questions are:

1. **What does the book cover?**
2. **Can you provide a review of the book?**
3. **Would you recommend any other resources specifically for the Russian system?**

Comment: Eric Schiller has written very many books. I bought some of them. I was not impressed. But I am a weak player and I know very little about chess.

Comment: @bof Please elaborate on 'not impressed'? Was the knowledge unoriginal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is D96/D97 classification - ECO D would be your best bet. It would be comprehensive in variations but in Chess Informant style.

I would add this:
Even though Eric Schiller is somewhat known for his error-prone books, this book *is* in it's second edition. I would venture to say that, as far as Schiller books go, it might not be all that bad. It really depends on your playing level. If you are a relatively weak player (say, 1400 rating or less), I'm sure it is fine to get your feet wet using this book. It is important to know how not to play an opening as well as know how to play it. It might be a good jumping off point for the opening. Of course, get an inexpensive used copy if possible.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unfamiliar with the book, it was published in 1988.  A 29 year old opening book it obsolete and shouldn't be studied. There are more recent books on the Grunfeld that cover the Russian variation, albeit from the black side.  You could also search for chess videos on that variation.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The original poster is interested in a particular opening variation and wanted to know if the book would be worth buying. The answer is that a 29 year old opening book is utterly obsolete and the purchase would be a waste of money and time.